# Export to PDF from ArcMap has Point Marker Symbols Appearing as Black Dots?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.3, pdf, citrix

I am having trouble exporting MXDs to PDF.  If I export and MXD to PDF some point symbols appear as black dots (not the colored dots they should be) and others do not.  This happens in different data sets in the same map.

I have embed fonts and convert marker symbols checked in the Export to PDF tool. I do not use non-USA thousand separators.

I have read this ESRI literature about diagnosing export problems:

http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17783

[image]

- Based on that document link above I can export the MXD to EMF, open the EMF in MS Paint and the EMF looks correct.
- IF I add the EMF to an MS Word document all the point symbols appear as crescents!?

I had the IT department rebuild my Citrix profile, reinstall the PDF drivers, and I did a reinstallation of ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.  The first map exported after all this work looked fine, but all subsequent exports revert back to the black dot problem.

Comment: A screenshot would be useful.

Comment: Are you opening the PDF in Acrobat Reader? If so, is Acrobat running through Citrix or do you have Acrobat installed locally? Also, is ArcGIS Desktop running locally or through Citrix?

Comment: Install a PDF print driver like [WinPDF](http://www.pdfdesk.com/winpdf.html) or [PDF995](http://www.pdf995.com/) and use this option to print rather than export.

Comment: Chad, I am using a local installation of ArcGIS 10.3.  I view the PDF using a locally installed version of PDF-Xchange PDF Viewer.

Comment: MDHald 1, thanks for the suggestion but this option will not really work for me for a couple of reasons.  I primarily export to PDF using the arcpy mapping module.  This method allows me to write to pdf, auto name the file and save it to the same directory, and log the file location, requester, and data to file.  Also, I work for a Tribal government and do not have administrative rights on my computer.  The IT department is understandably wary of third-party software.