# Problem with printing detailed navigation chart from PDF to HP Z5400PS

Tags: printing, pdf

We have been given a PDF of a navigation chart from the Norwegian Hydrographic Service to print on our HP Z5400 PS wide format printer.  All is well with the printed chart except that the symbol for a submarine pipeline is not printing properly in places, and also the symbol for a restricted area. Someone has said it's to do with the layers in the PDF.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: you need the font (they did not embed the font in the pdf )- similar to esri symbols issues in pdf's http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170092/export-to-pdf-from-arcmap-has-point-marker-symbols-appearing-as-black-dots